# How can i create neural networks in c#?

Tags: c#-2.0, neural-network

I'm doing object detection in c# using emgucv library. But i find it difficult to develop the neural network in c# for detecting the object? Please any body help me about this topic and how to test object in network???

Comment: "Anybody help me with broad area X" is not a great question. Please be more specific with phrasing.

Comment: What kind of neural network are you trying to develop?

Answer (score 7):

Here are the reference:

[Neural on C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/aforge_neuro.aspx)

[Neural Network Library project in C#](http://franck.fleurey.free.fr/NeuralNetwork/)

[C# Neural Class](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive407.html)

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but you may be able to use this simple library as a base OOP neural network library in C# that you can build further functionality:
http://allthingscs.blogspot.com/2011/04/neural-networks-with-c-part-1.html